# Where should my resource folder be with a runnable jar?

Tags: java, resources

In eclipse, i have a project i am working on with resources that i call like this for example

```
URL url = FighterComponent.class.getResource("/gfx/characters/");
File file = new File(url.getPath() + info.name + "/" + frame.path);
```

/gfx/ being a folder inside of res. res is my resource folder which i have linked by doing this:

run > run configurations... > Classpath > Select user entries > Advanced > Add folder

My question now is that where should the res folder be after i exported my project into a runnable jar for my friends to be able to test it? I tried putting it in the same folder as my jar and inside my jar and for both the URL was null.

Any idea ?

Comment: As the answers say, the resources need to be inside the jar. As a result, the code you show, creating a `File`, will not work, because the resources will be entries in a zip file, not files in their own right. You will need to manipulate them only as URLs or as streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name begins with a `'/'` `('\u002f')`, then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the `'/'`.

So, you should have a gfx/characters directory inside the jar file. Under this directory, if you have an image.jpg resource, you will have to retrieve it using:

```
URL url = TheClass.class.getResource("/gfx/characters/image.jpg");
```

You can also use the `getResourceAsStream()` to get an `InputStream` that you can read from.

Comment: I also tried that, didn't work. (Content from res into the jar)

Comment: Don't try to read files. Read from the InputStream resulted from calling getResourceAsStream. Don't put a res directory inside the jar but just gfx/...

Answer (score 0):

You can put it at the root of your jar. Then people will be able to access the resources by `/res/gfx/..`