# JAVA: How to specify resource path in .JAR file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path, export

I'm exporting my Java project to a Runnable JAR and I've included dependencies. However, upon running, I can't get the path to work. The path in my Eclipse client is specified as: "res/worlds/testmap.tmx", which is fine, because the res folder is in my project as a whole. Upon exporting my project into a JAR file, saving the JAR to my desktop, the path becomes: "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\res\worlds\testmap.tmx". It's missing the directory where it goes into the JAR file I exported. How can I go about doing this in my code?

Pictures related:

[The workspace working tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V83T7.png)

[The JAR file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq3b5.png)

Comment: You cannot access resources inside jars as files.

Comment: See the accepted answer at possible duplicate ["Where should my resource folder be with a runnable jar?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448501).